# C# with SQL Server setup in client pc

Tags: c#, sql-server, setup-project

I create C# with SQL Server database I try many ways to make setup file work on client PC. It's working fine on my PC, but not on client pc. I installed .NET framework; my application is installing, but not running. I hope someone can help me with this problem. I used Visual Studio 2017 and SQL Server 2014 and client PC there is no SQL Server or Visual Studio, I installed only .NET framework.

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Test_project.Properties.Settings.Test2ConnectionString"
            connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Test2.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: If your project uses SQL Server - you **must have** SQL Server installed at your client's site - either locally on that PC, or in their network accessible from that PC you're trying to install your software on

Comment: Your connection string specifies that a LocalDB instance must be installed and the data file must be in the same file as the EXE (unless you're suing ClickOnce). If that's not the case then you have to edit the connection string for the actual situation on the machine the app is running on.